# Cannot resolve "coin.transfer

Tags: pact

I'm learning the Pact language, and I'm looking at a contract already developed and available on the mainnet.

In this contract there is:

```
(coin.transfer owner ADMIN_ADDRESS (* (get-price) amount))
```

there is no table created in the contract called `coin` and the compiler gives me the error:

`Cannot resolve "coin.transfer`

Answer (score 3):

The `coin` contract exists on the blockchain.
I'm guessing you're trying to call coin.transfer locally in your REPL.

To do this - you will need to

1. Load the coin contract and any dependencies (such as the fungible interfaces) into your REPL first
2. Create any accounts you want to interact with (such as the accounts for `owner` `ADMIN_ADDRESS`

Then you should be able to interact with the `coin` contract as you would on the blockchain

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! Could you technically explain how to solve point 1? I am looking in the doc but i don't understand how i should load the coin contract

Comment: Sure - but best to ask it as a separate question